# TabActivity TextView set in content is not stretching as per screen; it is getting wrapped

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added four textviews in a LinearLayout as shown below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/aboutLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transparentbg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aboutTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/aboutTitle"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aboutDesc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="@string/aboutText"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/howToUse"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/howToUseTitle"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/howToUseDesc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="@string/howToUse"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the text is gettting wrapped, and the text is getting truncated. What could be wrong? This goes for a toss when I test in Samsung [Galaxy Note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_series), but in [Galaxy Nexus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus), it seems to be perfectly fine.

This view is set as content for the TabHost as shown below

```
final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, tabHost.getTabContentView(), true);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Altimeter")
        .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.altimeter_32))
        .setContent(R.id.altimeter));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings")
        .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage))
        .setContent(R.id.settingsAltimeter));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("About")
        .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details))
        .setContent(R.id.aboutLayout));
```

Text is set in strings like this:

`<string name="howToUse">1) Detects transformation gestures involving more than one pointer ("multitouch")  \nDetects transformation gestures involving more than one pointer ("multitouch") \n\n
        2)Detects transformation gestures involving more than one pointer ("multitouch") y.\n\n
        3) Detects transformation gestures involving more than one pointer ("multitouch") .\n\n
        4) Detects transformation gestures involving more than one pointer ("multitouch") \n\n
        5) Detects transformation gestures involving more than one pointer ("multitouch") \n\n</string>`

Comment: text obviously gets wrapped as you have given wrap content to it.what u want to do clear it first.

Comment: @AkashG : Did you mean width or height ? I had given fill_parent for height, but it did not work.

Comment: where u have given  fill_parent for height??The text is getting truncated is issued regarding width and not height.

Comment: @Akash: i have edited the code. I have done fillparent now in width, but still i can see the issue. The second and the third TextView is having paragraphs string.

Comment: Remove android:visibility="invisible" from linear layout

Comment: That was just temporary for toggling visibility

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13711/discussion-between-arun-abraham-and-akashg)

Answer (score -1):

It was a wrong theme that I had assigned to the activity that was causing this issue.